# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier UITableView two times

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

i have this that works:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
Item *objItem = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CustomCell *cell = nil;
cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierLONG];
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath tableView:tableView];

}
```

And i want to do something like this:

```
- (void)configureCell:(TimelineTextoFotoCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath tableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

Item *objItem = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.txtNota.text = objItem.nota;

 if ([cell.txtNota.text sizeWithFont:cell.txtNota.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.txtNota.frame.size.width, 1000.f)].height/cell.txtNota.font.pointSize < 2.0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierSHORT];
    } else {
    //should remain dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierLONG....
    }

//setup cell the same, for both cases.
}
```

It doesnt work. The cell always uses the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierLONG`, and i checked the line `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierSHORT];` gets executed. I need to change the identifier based on the fetched `objectAtIndexPath:indexPath`

Comment: Where are you creating the cells in the first place, before dequeuing them?

Comment: Im under ios5, so deqeue... should always return a cell. Correct me if im wrong please.

Comment: If you are using storyboard, then I can't correct you ;-)

Comment: yep, i am using storyboards, with prototypes. Im lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you *always* request a cell with identifierLONG in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Then you pass that over to `configureCell`, where you optionally try to replace that cell with one with identifierSHORT. I guess that might be too late because you already dequeued one with identifierLONG. To be honest, I never tried something like that, so I can't tell for sure whether that's the cause of your problem.

Did you already try something like this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    Item *objItem = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CustomCell *cell = nil;

    if (<<ToBeReplacedWithSomeConditionWhichOnlyUsesobjItem>>) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierSHORT];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierLONG];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath tableView:tableView];

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I cant, i need to use different cells depending on the height of a UITextField.. Any other clues?

Comment: This is the way to do it. You need to decide on which cell you want, before you dequeue it. So you'll need to do your size check on the text from your data model. Alternatively, have a single cell with an auto sizing text field, and adjust the height in the `heightForRow` delegate method.

Comment: Is that UITextField cell.txtNota? Do all 'identifierLONG-cells' (and respectively all 'identifierSHORT-cells') have the same UITextField (meaning they all have the same frame.size and font)? If yes, you should be able to create that ToBeReplacedCondition without actually dequeuing a cell.

Comment: Another possible cause of that problem might be that your variables identifierSHORT and identifierLONG actually have the same value. Did you check their values?

Comment: @PeterG. unfortunately no, they differ size.height but they do have same font. im trying to have to different customcells on for short text and another on for longer texts. So i need to calculate the lines and then decide which customcell to use.

Comment: @PeterG. yes the identifiers are ok.

Comment: @PeterG. i think that with both having the same size.width it should be sufficient to treat them the same and represent them with a copy of one of them in the tableviewcontroller so i can simulate the check. is that possible?

Comment: Yes. It was possible! Ive done it. thank you for your inspiration!!

Comment: Wow... I thought you had already given up and were looking for alternative solutions. Nice to see that you could solve your problem ;)